# How to group or sum up data within @ElementCollection by JPQL?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb

I have a class holds many to many relationship from a deal to transaction amounts

```
Class Deal{
.....

private String name;

private String department;

private DealType type;

@AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name="value.in.available", column=@Column(name="in_avl")),
    @AttributeOverride(name="value.in.unavailable", column=@Column(name="in_unv")),
    @AttributeOverride(name="value.out.available", column=@Column(name="out_avl")),
    @AttributeOverride(name="value.out.unavailable", column=@Column(name="out_unv"))
})
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Map<Transaction, AmountBucket> transactionAmounts= new TreeMap<Coffer, AmountBucket>();
}
```

Then Entity `AmountBucket` is something like this:

```
Class AmountBucket{
    private Amount in;
    private Amount out;
}

Class Amount{
    private BigDecimal available;
    private BigDecimal unavaiable;
}
```

But for @ElementCollection purpose the tree hierarchy stores in single table by using `@AttributeOverride`.

The goal here is to sum up the `transactionAmounts` regardless of `DealType`. If it didn't choose the lovely `@ElementCollection` feature then we can just made an inner join in the JPQL then group by, but when I try to group the stuff by JPQL with the ElementCollection structure, there is a problem:

```
Failed to execute query 
"SELECT NEW DEAL(d.name, d.department, SUM(d.transactionAmounts)) FROM 
Deal AS d GROUP BY d.name, d.department". 
Check the query syntax for correctness. See nested exception for details.; nested 
exception is <openjpa-2.2.0-r422266:1244990 nonfatal user error>    org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Failed to execute query ......
```

May be `d.transactionAmounts` cannot sum up because of it's `@CollectionElement`? I have a constructor that serves for this JPQL query:

```
public Deal(String name, String department, Map<Transaction, AmountBucket> transactionAmounts) {
    this.name= name;
    this.department= department;
    this.transactionAmounts= transactionAmounts;
    this.type = DealType.SUM;
}
```

I really don't see any syntax issue in the JPQL, and also fail to see any documentation about how to group, sum up values within `@ElementCollection`. Please help thanks.

Comment: Could you post a bit more of the stacktrace?

Comment: @Andrei I The stack trace really didn't tell much but only say the JPQL has syntax error. I bet there should be something else but OpenJPA doesn't output to the log.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in the constructor: it does not have the correct signature. It should have the following one:

```
public Deal(String name, String department, long transactionAmount);//you might try also with int instead of long
```

because `SUM(d.transactionAmounts)` returns a number, not a `MAP` as you have in your constructor.

Comment: thank you. But I think `transactionAmount` is with type `Map<Transaction, AmountBucket>` instead of Long. I was thinking to use `SELECT NEW DEAL(d.name, d.department, SUM(d.value.in.available), SUM(d.value.in.unavailable),SUM(d.value.out.available),SUM(d.value.out.unavailable))` but still not works. Because i think JPQL cannot recognize `value` as field of transactionAmount. Really pull my hair to find a way for sum up map values.

Comment: You did not understand that the `SUM()` expression in the JPQL returns a *number* represented by a long or int. It cannot be a MAP. If you want the constructor with 4 longs, it should work, but it id definitely not a MAP.

Comment: You are right. So how to retrieve a map's key or value in a JPQL anyway then I can construct the new entity with proper select SUM() query? Thanks.

Comment: I have seen your follow-up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20229155/how-to-access-map-field-in-jpa-via-jpql if that gets solved, please mark this as solved as well.