# How to access Map field in JPA via JPQL

Tags: jpa, orm, openjpa

for example, if there is an `@ElementCollection` file which is with a `Map` type, then if I try to get the map key or value field then how to process?

```
Class Deal{
.....

private String name;

private String department;

private DealType type;

@AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name="value.in.available", column=@Column(name="in_avl")),
    @AttributeOverride(name="value.in.unavailable", column=@Column(name="in_unv")),
    @AttributeOverride(name="value.out.available", column=@Column(name="out_avl")),
    @AttributeOverride(name="value.out.unavailable", column=@Column(name="out_unv"))
})
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    ......
}
```

So if I try to get something like this

```
select new SummaryAmount(SUM(t.value.in.available), SUM(t.value.in.unavailable),
SUM(t.value.out.available), SUM(t.value.out.unavailable)) from Deal AS d INNER 
JOIN d.transactionAmounts t GROUP by t.key;
```

Is it something possible can work out now? Everything is follow the book except I invent the `t.value` and `t.key` as I really don't know how to present map key and value in JPQL.Thanks

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT new SummaryAmount(SUM(VALUE(t).in.available), SUM(VALUE(t)in.unavailable),
SUM(VALUE(t).out.available), SUM(VALUE(t).out.unavailable)) from Deal AS d INNER 
JOIN d.transactionAmounts t GROUP by KEY(t);
```

And now an excerpt from the JPA specification:

> An identification variable qualified by the KEY, VALUE, or ENTRY
>   operator is a path expression. The KEY, VALUE, and ENTRY operators may
>   only be applied to identification variables that correspond to
>   map-valued associations or map-valued element collections. The type of
>   the path expression is the type computed as the result of the
>   operation; that is, the abstract schema type of the field that is the
>   value of the KEY, VALUE, or ENTRY operator (the map key, map value, or
>   map entry respectively).[53]
>
> The syntax for qualified identification variables is as follows.
>
> qualified_identification_variable :: =
>
> **KEY**(identification_variable) |
>
> **VALUE**(identification_variable) |
>
> **ENTRY**(identification_variable)
>
> A path expression using the KEY or VALUE operator can be further
>   composed. A path expression using the ENTRY operator is terminal. It
>   cannot be further composed and can only appear in the SELECT list of a
>   query.

Comment: Thanks for the constant assistance. Best answer ! :)